# installing openstack using devstack on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, openstack, git

when I run the ./stack.sh command to install openstack I get the following errors:
please help me

[image]
error: RPC failed; curl 56 GnuTLS recv error
(-9): Error decoding the received TLS packet.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
+functions-common:git_timed:729            [[ 128 -ne 124 ]]
+functions-common:git_timed:730            die 730 'git call failed: [git clone' https://opendev.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements --branch 'master]'
+functions-common:die:264                  local exitcode=0
+functions-common:die:265                  set +o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:774:git_clone
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:654:git_timed
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:730:die
[ERROR] /opt/stack/devstack/functions-common:730 git call failed: [git clone https://opendev.org/openstack/requirements.git /opt/stack/requirements --branch master]
Error on exit
/opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py:22: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
from distutils import spawn
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2022-12-29-234955.txt for details

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: I need help please

Answer (score 0):

I've spent hours trying to find way and find these solution:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000
git config --global core.longpaths true
git config --global core.compression -1

git clone --depth=1 https://opendev.org/openstack/neutron.git --branch stable/zed
```

Also possibly you can download tar.gz for each repo and use them directly, but I'm not sure how to configure devstack for that.